# What is the purpose of multiple type-casting in java?

Tags: java, casting

I came across a code fragment in java today, as follows:

```
long longValue = 100;
byte b = (byte)(short)(int)longValue;
byte byteValue = 100;
long l = (long)(int)(short)byteValue;
System.out.println(b+l);
```

What is the purpose of type casting multiple times, from int to short to byte and from short to int to long? Would it make any difference if I cast directly from long to byte or vice-versa?

**The above code did not make any difference even when there was no explicit type casting!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the purpose of type casting multiple times, from int to short to byte and from short to int to long?

There is no purpose. Period.

```
byte b = (byte)(short)(int) longValue;
long l = (long)(int)(short) byteValue;
```

are 100% equivalent to:

```
byte b = (byte) longValue;
long l = byteValue;
```

---

The code in your question is probably one of the following:

- an indication that the author of the code doesn't understand Java,
- a test ... to see if >>you<< understand Java,
- part of a unit test for a Java compiler or similar, or
- code that was *generated* by some tool, which human beings shouldn't need to read, and a compiler will gleefully optimize.

---

There are one or two situations where a chain of typecasts is actually useful.  Here is one:

```
int ch = ...
System.out.println("char is '" + (char)(byte) ch + "'");
```

Here, the `(byte)` *narrows* the `int` to an 8-bit signed value, and then the `(char)` *widens* it to a 16 bit unsigned value.  Then the `+` operator causes `Character.toString(char)` to be used to convert the value to a String.  (If you leave out the `(char)`, the value will be formatted as a number, not a character ...)

(Note: there are problems with the above code.  I am using it to illustrate that chaining type-casts is *sometimes* a useful thing to do.)